# Does "when" mean what time or the occasion in "Do you remember when we went to Norway?"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> **Do you remember when we went to Norway?** That was a good trip. (Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary)

Does the sentence mean 1 or 2?

> 1. Do you remember at what time we went to Norway?
> 2. Do you remember the occasion when we went to Norway?

I think gramatically speaking, both interpretations are possible, but the second sentence suggests (2) makes sense here.

Comment: It is not: Do you remember what time we went to Norway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Do you remember when" can be used in different contexts to mean slightly different things.

1. It could be used to invite someone to remember a specific occasion or a *period of time*. It doesn't necessarily require the listener to respond with a time or date, it can just be to invoke a shared memory.

> **Example**
> "Do you remember when we went to Norway?"
> "Yes, that was such a great vacation".

2. It could be used to request the response of a *specific date or time*, when you need that information and you think the other person may know.

> **Example**
> "Do you remember when we arrived here?"
> "Yes, we got here at 2:15pm"

Comment: Sorry to bother again. Does the second sentence in the OP "that was a good trip" suggest either reading is more likely over the other？